# Apache Ignite embedded cluster mode

Tags: java, config, cluster-computing, ignite

I have run two application with embedded mode having the following config:

```
public IgniteConfigurer config() {
    return cfg -> {
        // The node will be started as a client node.
        cfg.setClientMode(false);
        // Classes of custom Java logic will be transferred over the wire from this app.
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);
        // Setting up an IP Finder to ensure the client can locate the servers.
        final TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList(cacheServerIp));
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));
        // Cache Metrics log frequency. If 0 then log print disable.
        cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(Integer.parseInt(cacheMetricsLogFrequency));
        // setting up storage configuration
        final DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
        storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        storageCfg.setStoragePath(cacheStorage);
        // setting up data region for storage
        final DataRegionConfiguration defaultRegion = new DataRegionConfiguration();
        defaultRegion.setName(cacheDefaultRegionName);
        // Sets initial memory region size. When the used memory size exceeds this value, new chunks of memory will be allocated
        defaultRegion.setInitialSize(Long.parseLong(cacheRegionInitSize));
        storageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(defaultRegion);
        cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);
        cfg.setWorkDirectory(cacheStorage);
        final TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
        // Sets message queue limit for incoming and outgoing messages
        communicationSpi.setMessageQueueLimit(Integer.parseInt(cacheTcpCommunicationSpiMessageQueueLimit));
        cfg.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);
        final CacheCheckpointSpi cpSpi = new CacheCheckpointSpi();
        cfg.setCheckpointSpi(cpSpi);
        final FifoQueueCollisionSpi colSpi = new FifoQueueCollisionSpi();
        // Execute all jobs sequentially by setting parallel job number to 1.
        colSpi.setParallelJobsNumber(Integer.parseInt(cacheParallelJobs));
        cfg.setCollisionSpi(colSpi);
        // set failure handler for auto connection if ignite server stop/starts.
        cfg.setFailureHandler(new StopNodeFailureHandler());
    };
}
```

**App1** put data in cache where as **App2** read data from cache. I have set local IP i.e `ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));`

So locally both apps i.e app1 and app2 connected on cluster. When i put same config on server with IP change i.e `ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("server1.com:47500..47509"));`

Both servers i.e app1 and app2 not connected in cluster.

Is it embedded work only when all apps i.e app1 and app2 are on same machine?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [a static TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery#static-ip-finder) instead to locate the issue. By default, TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder tries to scan all available hosts to discover Ignite nodes, and depending on timeouts this might take a while.

Assuming both of your nodes are still running on the same machine, you might keep the localhost configuration: "127.0.0.1:47500..47509". "server1.com:47500..47509" should also work if DNS name "server1.com" resolves to the correct IP address, the best way to check that - just to run a ping command to check how localhost and server1.com are being resolved.

If you are running on different machines, then you need to have a list of addresses rather than a singleton: "server1.com:47500..47509", "server2.com:47500.47509" etc.

It's also recommended to check whether the ports are opened and probably to configure a [localHost](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration#discovery) explicitly if there are many different interfaces available.

Comment: both servers i.e app1 (app1.com) and app2 (app2.com) running on a different server and both are trying to connect with server2.com:47500.47509.

Comment: When I tried with TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder
  both app1 and aap2 start on their machine even though I have given IP address to server1.com:47500..47509.
  When I change to static  a static TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder  with server1.com:47500..47509 I am getting error like  Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (make sure IP finder addresses are correct and firewalls are disabled on all host machines) server1/<<ip_address>>:47500, server1/<<ip_address>>:47501........server1/<<ip_address>>:47509

Comment: Yep, you need to place all your addresses in a static finder so that each node can connect to another. So you need to have THE SAME list of addresses for every server, i.e. for server1 AND server2 it should be: ["server1:47500..47510", "server2:47500..47510"], if you would have a third server, it also needs to be added to ALL nodes: ["server1:47500..47510", "server2:47500..47510", "server3...."]